# Default value of serial fields changes after restore

Tags: postgresql

Today I found a strange behavior after restoring a PostgreSQL database: the schema of all `serial` fields default values are trimmed out.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE testschema.testtable
(
   id serial, 
   name character varying(255), 
   CONSTRAINT pk_testtable PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE
)
;


SELECT a.attnum, n.nspname, c.relname, d.adsrc AS default_value
FROM pg_attribute AS a
JOIN pg_class AS c ON a.attrelid = c.oid
JOIN pg_namespace AS n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_attrdef AS d ON d.adrelid = c.oid AND d.adnum = a.attnum
WHERE a.attnum > 0 
  AND n.nspname = 'testschema' 
  AND c.relname = 'testtable'
```

The `id`'s default_value is `nextval('testschema.testtable_id_seq'::regclass)`.

After restore, default_value changes to `nextval('testtable_id_seq'::regclass)` and INSERT's start to fail as the sequence can´t be found on it's schema.

**Backup**
`$ pg_dump -F c -Z 9 -b -h localhost -U postgres -f backup dbname`

**Restore**
`$ pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -l backup > backup.list`
`$ pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost --disable-triggers -O -d dbname -S postgres -Fc -L backup.list backup`

Is this some backup/restore problem? What am I doing wrong? BTW, PostgreSQL version is 9.1.3 x64 running on Windows (dev machine), but can be reproduced on Linux too.

Answer (score 4):

I ran the same process as you did, but got different results.  Restoring the database using your command didn't work when trying to overwrite the same database because you didn't use the -c --clean option.  Restoring to a new database with the same pg_restore command worked. Inserting new records was still possible however.

Here are the steps I took.

**Create the database**

> `createdb testdatabase`

**Create the schema**

> `psql -d testdatabase -c 'create schema testschema;'`

**Create the table**

> psql -d testdatabase

```
CREATE TABLE testschema.testtable(
  id serial, name character varying(255), 
  CONSTRAINT pk_testtable PRIMARY KEY (id)
) with (OIDS=false);
```

> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "testtable_id_seq"
>   for serial column "testtable.id" NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY
>   will create implicit index "pk_testtable" for table "testtable" CREATE
>   TABLE

**Insert some records**

```
testdatabase=# insert into testschema.testtable (name) values('person1'),('person2');
INSERT 0 2
```

**Backup the database**

```
pg_dump -F c -Z 9 -b -h localhost -U postgres -f backup testdatabase
```

**Create the backup list file**

pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost -l backup > backup.list

**Relevant contents of backup.list**

> 2639; 1262 16468 DATABASE - testdatabase postgres 163; 1259 16472
>   TABLE testschema testtable postgres 162; 1259 16470 SEQUENCE
>   testschema testtable_id_seq postgres 2643; 0 0 SEQUENCE OWNED BY
>   testschema testtable_id_seq postgres 2644; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET testschema
>   testtable_id_seq postgres 2633; 2604 16475 DEFAULT testschema id
>   postgres 2636; 0 16472 TABLE DATA testschema testtable postgres 2635;
>   2606 16477 CONSTRAINT testschema pk_testtable postgres

**Restore the backup**

```
pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost --disable-triggers -O -d testdatabase -S postgres -Fc -L backup.list backup
```

pg_restore sends back errors

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema
>   "testschema" already exists pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC
>   entry 163; 1259 16472 TABLE testtable postgres pg_restore: [archiver
>   (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "testtable_id_seq"
>   already exists

**Restore to another database**

```
createdb testdatabase2
pg_restore -U postgres -h localhost --disable-triggers -O -d testdatabase2 -S postgres -Fc -L backup.list backup
```

Did not get any errors

**Insert more records**

```
psql -d testdatabase2

testdatabase2=# insert into testschema.testtable (name) values('person2'),('person3');
INSERT 0 2
```

**View records**

```
testdatabase2=# select * from testschema.testtable;

 id |  name   
----+---------
  1 | person1
  2 | person2
  3 | person2
  4 | person3
```

**View the table structure for testschema.testtable**

```
pg_dump --schema-only -t testschema.testtable testdatabase2
```

As you mentioned in your question, postgresql does rewrite the default value

> ALTER TABLE ONLY testtable ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT
>   nextval('testtable_id_seq'::regclass);

**Conclusion**

Using your exact same commands, errors did occur when trying to restore over the same database, but when restoring to a new database, adding new records was possible.

You must add the -c or --clean, to drop existing objects so that they can be restored by pg_restore.

```
pg_restore -c -U postgres -h localhost --disable-triggers -O -d testdatabase -S postgres -Fc -L backup.list backup
```

Postgresql did rewrite the default value for your serial column as you mentioned in your question, but insertions were still possible.

**Updated Answer**

When using the query you provided, it is true I don't see the testschema in the search path after restoring the database.

```
testdatabase=# SELECT a.attnum, n.nspname, c.relname, d.adsrc AS default_value FROM pg_attribute AS a JOIN pg_class AS c ON a.attrelid = c.oid JOIN pg_namespace AS n ON c.relnamespace = n.oid LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_attrdef AS d ON d.adrelid = c.oid AND d.adnum = a.attnum WHERE a.attnum > 0   AND n.nspname = 'testschema'  AND c.relname = 'testtable';
 attnum |  nspname   |  relname  |             default_value             
--------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------------
      1 | testschema | testtable | nextval('testtable_id_seq'::regclass)
      2 | testschema | testtable |
```

But, when I use \d testschema.testtable I do see the testschema in the definition of NEXTVAL

```
testdatabase=# \d testschema.testtable;
                                    Table "testschema.testtable"
 Column |          Type          |                             Modifiers                             
--------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer                | not null default nextval('testschema.testtable_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | character varying(255) |
```

I found this on Postgresql's forums, which talks about the differences we are both seeing.

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-admin/2009-06/msg00070.php

Comment: You're right, `INSERT`s still working (I was testing through my app, I didn't think at the time to test through psql, my bad), but that rewrite is still causing meerrors: I'm using an ORM that relies on the default value, and since there's no schema info the call to `nextval` fails.

Comment: Updated my answer. If you use \d testschema.testtable do you see the testschema in the NEXTVAL definition?